# Reset SPAN value to Default

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML code and would like to reset the SPAN value back to 0. Textarea and textbox both works fine.

HTML

```
<div id="Match">FULL MATCH: <span class="fullMatch">0</span></div>
<input type="text" id="c-match" value="" />
```

JS

```
jQuery('.c-reset').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('span').text(''); //this only removes the values without reverting back to 0
    jQuery('textarea, #c-match').val(function() {
        return this.defaultValue;
    });
});
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Um.. `jQuery('span').text('0');` ?

Comment: Tried `$("#Match span").html(this.defaultValue); return this.defaultValue;` ?

Comment: DOM element that are not form control elements don't have a default value. You have to explicitly set their content to what should be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `html()` instead of `text()`:

`jQuery('span').html('0');`

*Update:* span doesn't have a default value, you have to manually set it's content.

`jQuery('span').text('0');` will also work

Comment: this actually worked. Thanks. Will try Guilherme's suggestion also

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover would be nice of you to accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: sure, will accept in 10mins :). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this
I will suggest two that I personally consider the best:

### Store default value in variable

```
jQuery.ready(function(){//ready function
    var spanDefault = jQuery('#Match span').text();
    jQuery('.c-reset').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('textarea, #c-match').val(function() {
            setTimetou(function(){
                jQuery('#Match span').text(spanDefault);
            }, 1);
            return this.defaultValue;
        });
    });
});
```

### Using data attribute

Set in `<span>` the attribute `data-value="0"`, see:

```
<div id="Match">FULL MATCH: <span data-value="0" class="fullMatch">0</span></div>
<input type="text" id="c-match" value="" />
```

JS:

```
jQuery('.c-reset').on('click', function() {
    var fullMatch = jQuery('#c-match span');
    fullMatch.text(fullMatch.data("value"));

    jQuery('textarea, #c-match').val(function() {
        return this.defaultValue;
    });
});
```

Comment: let me try your suggestion also

Comment: this removes the value entirely

Comment: Forgive me, now I understand what you need, I edited my answer again.